# When I resize my browser the headings, navigation bars overlaps. It doesn't fits with the browser

Tags: html, css

When I place the width of by web page as 100% it fits to the browser. But when I re-adjust the size of the browser the navigation bar I used overlaps and all the positions go wrong. I can't figure out the mistake yet. I will post the css and the html code below. Please someone help me to fix my web page.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo12">
            <h2 style="position:absolute; left:20px; top:2px; color:#FFFFFF;">
                <a>
                    <font face="verdana">PHIS</font>

                    <small>Public Health Information System-Sri Lanka</small>
                </a>
            </h2>

        </div>
    <div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="HomePHI.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul id="SubNav">

                    <li id="AccessFormPHI"><a href=""">Data Entry</a></li>

                    <li id="DataEntry"><a href="">Edit Temporary Forms</a></li>

                    <li id="ViewData"><a href="">View Data</a></li>

                    <li id="ViewAggregatedData"><a href="">Data Aggregation</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Profile</a>
            <ul id="SubNav">

                    <li id="AccessForm"><a href="">View and Maintain Profile</a></li>

                    <li id="ChangePassword"><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="login/index.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*    Height of the navigation bar became shorter   */
.main {
    width: 100%;
    font: 13px Georgia, "verdana", "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #FFFFFFF;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    height: 1000px;
    left: 0px;
}

/* No difference was appeared*/
#cssmenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
}

/* Adjust the olor of the  navigation bar  */
.logo12 {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 10px;
    /*padding-left: 60px; */ 
    top: 0%;
    height: 6%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#084B8A ,#0B173B);
}

/* Adjust the place where navigation   */
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%; /* change to 390px to 350px */
    top: 20px;
    display: inline;
}

#menu ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width :700px; /*change to 60% to 800px*/
}

/* upto now no difference  */
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: 130px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

/* Adjust the width of the sub navigation bar  */
#menu ul li ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

/* Adjust the color of the sub navigation  bar */
#menu li ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px; 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 28px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#084B8A ,#0B173B); #726E6D; /*Menu Hover Color*/
    border: 1;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
    width: auto;
}

/* Upto now no difference was visible   */
#menu li li {
    list-style: none;
}

/* Color of sub navigation bar letters became gray */
#menu li li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Letters hover color red in the sub navigation bar */
#menu li li a:hover {
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Upto now no difference */
li#main1 {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

/* Main navigation bar disappeared  */
#menu a {
    padding-right: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #BDBDBD;
    font: cambria;
}

/* Upto now no difference  */
#menu ul li a:hover {
    /* background: #D8D8D8; /*a tag hover color*/
    padding: 5px; /*change to 12px to 5px*/
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: use floats instead of position absolute

Comment: Possible because of your absolute positioned elements.

Comment: Do I need to use float always instead of using absolute. Is this common for each and every tag I'm using? I meant do I need to use float throughout the website?

Comment: It's not a good idea to just copy your whole code in here and let others fix it. Remove the unnecessary parts and check your HTML again. You have `div`'s inside of `ul`. There should only be `li`'s. Also The `font` tag inside your `h2` isn't closed properly.

Comment: why not do some research with bing or google on "float" and inheritance.  you can't expect us to just g I've you the answers without some effort on your part.

Comment: :) Thanks alot for your valuable advices friends. Well this was a code I tried to do by myself. And I must say I did this even to this much by referring internet. didn't copy it by anyone. And if someone can give me some hints to fix, it will be really appreciable. Jst need some advices. that's all... :)

Comment: Thanks  kleinfreund will do that... :)

Comment: I've made another edit to your post. In your HTML, check your first lines with the `h2`. The `</font>` tag should be right after `<font face="verdana">PHIS`. Also `<span></span>` is useless there. You can remove it.

Comment: Well, okay... the `font`-tag should be wrapped around `PHIS` like this: `<font face="verdana">PHIS</font>`. You will find out, that this is not an appropriate way to format text. You already use CSS for the rest. With `span` and CSS you could achieve the same. ;)

Comment: Well... Thanks alot kleinfreund ... will fix it... :) (y)

Comment: @ kleinfreund: The problem is with main and tha main navigation bar. cant I give width:100% in the css file. Is it why it shrinks than the re-sized browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative width for CSS,for example:

```
.main, .header{width:100%;}
```

Comment: You have a spate of edits that are too minor to be approved.  Use the edits to add clarity and really enhance the post.

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to your navigation CSS. I know this is an old post, but seems to have no solution yet.